# can't debug code by eclipse by bug: terminated, exit values: 1 javaw.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, terminate, javaw

I can't debug my Code on eclipse anymore. 
The termenating of the Code occurs during the two runs of my eclipse Code.

I have no idea, why the process is terminated appers from one Moment to the next. 
Does this appers on the "jdk" or "jre" Version? I suppose not, because Debugging works for Long time before this happens

Furthermore the Debug Perspective Shows the following Messages:

> ExpiringCache$1(LinkedHashMap.afterNodeInsertion(boolean)line:
>   not available
>
> ExpiringCache$1(HashMap.putVal(int,K,V,boolean,boolean)line: not
>   available
>
> ExpiringCache$1(HashMap.put(K,Vboolean,boolean)line: not
>   available
>
> UsageTrackerClient§4run() line: not available

and several more...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which version of eclipse? Which version of JDK?

Comment: eclipse : Neon. 1a Release (4.6.1); jdk: jdk-8u74-windows-x64

Comment: Consider [this](http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-a-simple-in-memory-cache-in-java-lightweight-cache/http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-a-simple-in-memory-cache-in-java-lightweight-cache/). The application under test may have critical sections where if you introduce a debugger induced delay the code times out.

Comment: Unfortunately this side is not available. Do you have an idea, if I changed any configuration without taken a notice or anything else?   How can i fix this?

Comment: @friedrich.schiller http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-a-simple-in-memory-cache-in-java-lightweight-cache/

Comment: so i have to implement this class to look, whats going on in the Cache? Why does this bug occurs now, after it will work for several weeks?

Comment: No idea. Has the break point always been at  the same line of code? Or is this a new break point?  My hypothesis is that you are trying to break inside a critical section that is under the control of a timer. Don't do that.  Instead, either turn the timer off (or set the timeout value really high) or save the desired data in strings that you can inspect at a break point after the critical section.

Comment: The bug was about the windows firewall. This blocked my embedded DB H2...